# How to get Jenkins "Console Output" after triggering build remotely?

Tags: perl, jenkins

I am using a Perl script to trigger a build in Jenkins using LWP modules.  This works but after executing the job, I would like to parse the console output.

Is there someway to get this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Log into Jenkins and take a look at the bottom of the webpage near the right hand side and click on the `REST API` link. This will give you information about the Jenkins [RESTful API](http://www.restapitutorial.com) which is a great way to pull information off of Jenkins once you understand how to construct the URL.

And, here's how you get the console text:

```
$ curl "${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/lastBuild/consoleText"
```

You can use Perl's various [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) modules to talk to Jenkins.

Comment: Ugh… I was super excited when I saw this but it doesn't include the timestamps in the log messages!!! At least on version 1.595

Comment: I think the time stamps are not part of the log. It's an option for Jenkins to insert the time stamps when you view the log  
If you replace `consoleText` with `consoleFull` you'll get the log in HTML. You then need to parse that of course to extract the content.
On Windows you can get that for free with Powershell.  
    $resp = Invoke-Webrequest "$(JENKINS_URL)/job/$(JOB_NAME)/lastBuild/consoleFull"  
    $resp.ParsedHtml.body.innerText > someFile.log
(Powershell Core that is available also on Linux doesn't include ParsedHtml in the object due to a requirement to a MS DLL)

Comment: And now I found the real solution to this :D
`${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/lastBuild/timestamps?appendLog&elapsed=HH:mm:ss.S`

Comment: @Ingemar I believe the `timestamps` api method is provided by the [Timestamper plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Timestamper). It also offers parameters like `startLine`, `endLine`, `locale`, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to include the pending build too? When I trigger a build it takes 2 top 3 seconds to initialize, during that time `latestBuild` indeed returns the previous build. I hate to add a sleep or something.

Comment: I am getting authentication failure even after passing ?token={tokenname} as a request parameter with the above URL. Anything I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the log from another Jenkins job that runs on the master, you can do it from a chained (child) job without needing to send an http GET.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974193/1580627.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Log Parser Plugin` for Jenkins. Read the [page number 24 here](http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/9781849517409-Chapter-01.pdf) for the configuration and other details.