# Jenkins "Console Output" log location in filesystem

Tags: jenkins

I want to access and grep Jenkins Console Output as a post build step in the same job that creates this output. Redirecting logs with `>> log.txt` is not a solution since this is not supported by my build steps.

Build:

```
echo "This is log"
```

Post build step:

```
grep "is" path/to/console_output
```

Where is the specific log file created in filesystem?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

@Bruno Lavit has a great answer, but if you want you can just access the log and download it as txt file to your workspace from the job's URL:

```
${BUILD_URL}/consoleText
```

Then it's only a matter of downloading this page to your `${Workspace}`

- You can use "`Invoke ANT`" and use the GET target
- On Linux you can use wget to download it to your workspace
- etc.

Good luck!

Edit: 
The actual log file on the file system is not on the slave, but kept in the Master machine. You can find it under: `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/lastSuccessfulBuild/log`

If you're looking for another build just replace `lastSuccessfulBuild` with the build you're looking for.

Comment: In the past, I tried the solution proposed by @Dvir669 and the wget command wasn't getting the full console log. That's why I've used the method described in my solution. So if you want to work on your build log in a post build step action, my solution is better (I think).

Comment: This fails for my Jenkins due to the folder being called 'lastSuccessful' only. But while a build is running, 'lastSuccessful' is some prior successful build not the current build. The current build only becomes the last successful one if it finishes successfully.

Comment: This also fails if the build job is inside a folder. JOB_NAME does not contain the '/jobs/' intermediate folders that are present with a folder.

Comment: Which Jenkins version are you using?

Comment: wget would need user_id/password and but I don't want to put it in the config. How can I use wget to download consoleText with existing authentication from which job is running?

Comment: I had to remove the / after {BUILD_URL}. I also had to follow the URL for it was giving me moved. Like so: curl -L --insecure -u USER:TOKEN ${BUILD_URL}consoleText -o ${WORKSPACE}/${filename}.txt

Comment: Guys. This answer is from 2016, it's been many Jenkins versions since then. I'm no longer working with Jenkins, so if something changes the flow or anything changed in the parameters feel free to add the right location/parameters :)

Comment: In my case, `$JENKINS_HOME` was not set on my master machine, but the log's location was `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<job_name>/branches/<branch_name>/builds/<build_number>/log` (machine runs on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 15):

Jenkins stores the console log on master.  If you want programmatic access to the log, and you are running on master, you can access the log that Jenkins already has, without copying it to the artifacts or having to GET the http job URL.

From http://javadoc.jenkins.io/archive/jenkins-1.651/hudson/model/Run.html#getLogFile(), this returns the File object for the console output (in the jenkins file system, this is the "log" file in the build output directory).

In my case, we use a chained (child) job to do parsing and analysis on a parent job's build.

When using a groovy script run in Jenkins, you get an object named "build" for the run.  We use this to get the http://javadoc.jenkins.io/archive/jenkins-1.651/hudson/model/Build.html for the upstream job, then call this job's .getLogFile().

Added bonus; since it's just a File object, we call .getParent() to get the folder where Jenkins stores build collateral (like test xmls, environment variables, and other things that may not be explicitly exposed through the artifacts) which we can also parse.

Double added bonus; we also use matrix jobs.  This sometimes makes inferring the file path on the system a pain.  .getLogFile().getParent() takes away all the pain.

Comment: If my job is running on child node , how can I copy the console logs to a file in my child node's workspace . 'build' wil copy logs from master node right ? Can we copy directly from child's console to file without master's involvement.

Answer (score 13):

Log location:

```
${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log
```

Get log as a text and save to workspace:

```
cat ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log >> log.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the Jenkins instance is a slave, as the logs are stored on the master instance.

Answer (score 12):

You can install this [Jenkins Console log](https://github.com/cboylan/jenkins-log-console-log) plugin to write the log in your workspace as a post build step.

You have to [build the plugin yourself](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) and [install the plugin manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950408/how-to-install-a-plugin-in-jenkins-manually).

Next, you can add a post build step like that:

[image]

With an additional post build step (shell script), you will be able to grep your log.

I hope it helped :)

Comment: However it seems like a small plugin, I still think that it might be achieved without any additional installations. There must be a way that this plugin gets console output. But how and from where?

Comment: I tried installing this plugin, changed zip to hpi, and tried uploading from advanced option in manage plugins, but it is giving error `A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins.`

Comment: @Sweety Did you build the plugin before uploading from the advanced section? You have to get the source from Github, build this plugin and upload the hpi file. There is a link on how to build a Jenkins plugin in my original post.

Answer (score 11):

For very large output logs it could be difficult to open (network delay, scrolling). This is the solution I'm using to check big log files:

```
    https://${URL}/jenkins/job/${jobName}/${buildNumber}/
```

in the left column you see:  `View as plain text`. Do a **right** mouse click on it and choose `save links as`. Now you can save your big log as .txt file. Open it with notepad++ and you can go through your logs easily without network delays during scrolling.

Comment: Finally the easiest solution

Answer (score 4):

I found the console output of my job in the browser at the following location:

`http://[Jenkins URL]/job/[Job Name]/default/[Build Number]/console`

Answer (score 3):

This is designed for use when you have a shell script build step. Use only the first two lines to get the file name.

You can get the console log file (using bash magic) for the current build from a shell script this way and check it for some error string, failing the job if found:

```
logFilename=${JENKINS_HOME}/${JOB_URL:${#JENKINS_URL}}
logFilename=${logFilename//job\//jobs\/}builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log

grep "**Failure**" ${logFilename} ; exitCode=$?
[[ $exitCode -ne 1 ]] && exit 1
```

You have to build the file name by taking the JOB_URL, stripping off the leading host name part, adding in the path to JENKINS_HOME, replacing "/job/" to "/jobs/" to handle all nested folders, adding the current build number and the file name.

The grep returns 0 if the string is found and 2 if there is a file error. So a 1 means it found the error indication string. That makes the build fail.

Comment: I receive: WorkflowScript: 15: unexpected char: '#' @ line 15, column 50.
   e=${JENKINS_HOME}/${JOB_URL:${#JENKINS_U
                                 ^

1 error

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution would be:

```
curl  http://jenkinsUrl/job/<Build_Name>/<Build_Number>/consoleText -OutFile <FilePathToLocalDisk>
```

or for the last successful build...

```
curl  http://jenkinsUrl/job/<Build_Name>/lastSuccessfulBuild/consoleText -OutFile <FilePathToLocalDisk>
```

Comment: That is a great idea, but the -OutFile did not work for me. The following worked a little better:

curl ${BUILD_URL}consoleFull -o ${TargetDir}/MyLog.txt

Unfortunately, Jenkins only sends part of the log, no matter what I do.

Comment: @Tihamer I think I'm facing the same issue when the logs are truncated when I'm saving them to a file. Did you find a solution to this by any chance?

Comment: @anechkayf - Sorry, I ran into that problem at a previous job, and have not touched Jenkins code since then. So I don't remember.  :-(
I suspect that curl may be running into limits set by the server, which you hopefully have have some access to (or at least can talk to someone who administers it).

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to jenkins master, either directly or just to the folders using any persistentent volumes. Below is the example path to fetch the log file.

Can see the portion from data folder, which is your jenkins folder.

[image: folder path]