# Jenkins, console output, parse, log

Tags: logging, jenkins, console, continuous-integration

society! I need your help. I'm QE and I need to solve one problem, what happened to me. I need to find the way, how I can parse the console output with a number of tests(total and fail) and put this on the subject of my email. I tried [log parser](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin), not works for me or I don't have idea how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parse logs, I think you should go about it with a different approach.  I believe Jenkins (JUnit) stores the test results as artefacts.  I'm sure there's a plugin that will let Jenkins mail you the test results in HTML format upon failure -- in fact I'm almost sure Jenkins can do this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a jenkins plugin, you could try downloading the logs (use `.../path/to/build/consoleText` instead of `.../path/to/build/console` to remove timestamps and other things). You can use `cURL` (or `wget` for linux) to download it as a txt file and parse it as you would any other plaintext file.

If you don't want to download it, and you have access to do things on master, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974193/4618553).

> Jenkins stores the console log on master. If you want programmatic
>   access to the log, and you are running on master, you can access the
>   log that Jenkins already has, without copying it to the artifacts or
>   having to GET the http job URL.
>
> From
>   http://javadoc.jenkins.io/archive/jenkins-1.651/hudson/model/Run.html#getLogFile(),
>   this returns the File object for the console output (in the jenkins
>   file system, this is the "log" file in the build output directory).
>
> In my case, we use a chained (child) job to do parsing and analysis on
>   a parent job's build.
>
> When using a groovy script run in Jenkins, you get an object named
>   "build" for the run. We use this to get the
>   http://javadoc.jenkins.io/archive/jenkins-1.651/hudson/model/Build.html
>   for the upstream job, then call this job's .getLogFile().
>
> Added bonus; since it's just a File object, we call .getParent() to
>   get the folder where Jenkins stores build collateral (like test xmls,
>   environment variables, and other things that may not be explicitly
>   exposed through the artifacts) which we can also parse.
>
> Double added bonus; we also use matrix jobs. This sometimes makes
>   inferring the file path on the system a pain.
>   .getLogFile().getParent() takes away all the pain.