# How to save the commands history of a Jenkins build run?

Tags: shell, jenkins, command-line, jenkins-pipeline, command-line-interface

I wrote a declarative Jenkins pipeline and would like to track the CLI commandos executed by Jenkins. To do this, I added a stage and the step `sh 'history -a'` in it:

```
pipeline {
    options {
        ...
    }
    agent {
        node {
            ...
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'hostname'
                sh 'pwd'
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
        stage('History') {
            steps {
                sh 'history -a'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        ...
    }
}
```

But that is not working:

```
Console Output
...
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Tear Down)
[Pipeline] sh
+ history -a
/path/to/project-root@tmp/durable-66ba15cc/script.sh: 1: history: not found
[Pipeline] }
...
```

Other Linux commands like `hostname`, `ls`, or `pwd` are working fine.

**Why does `history` run into an error? How to store the shell commands called by Jenkins in the context of a pipeline?**

Comment: Why? Because each `sh` steps creates its own shell session which is discarded when the function call returns. How? [Maybe this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853803/how-to-echo-shell-commands-as-they-are-executed) and then filter the Jenkins log for messages starting with "+ ".

Answer (score 0):

That specific error that you are getting I think it is only because the agent where you are running sh, does not have the history cmd available - `history: not found`

If you can store the sh commands... If you want only the sh commands, I think you need to write to a file that you create at the beginning, where you write to everytime you have a sh step,  or you can just use the pipeline log file (the output console).

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386581/jenkins-console-output-log-location-in-filesystem) a thread about the location of the pipeline or build logs, in case it helps.